# How to create Conceptual map using d3

Tags: d3.js

I am new to d3, my requirement requires to create a map as in this link:
http://www.findtheconversation.com/concept-map/

Can anyone guide on any D3 diagram or layout close to this.
I tried with force layout with rect and circle nodes and modifying the links and paths, but still it does not seem appealing.

Any guidance would be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: This conceptual map at the given URL is really interesting. I tried to get information from the HTML but I didn't see any info. It could be an internal development.

Comment: I found a page with the code for that example at: http://czcodezone.blogspot.com/2015/01/d3-simple-javascript-class-wrapper-for_25.html

Answer (score 0):

I've found this example that looks a bit like the very impressive data representation in the link.

http://bl.ocks.org/virtuald/ea7438cb8c6913196d8e